# direction of a packet in a pcap file

Tags: python, scapy, tor, fingerprinting

I have captured .pcap file for a webpage and I have read it through scapy with python. I was wondering if there is a way to determine the direction of a packet. I am trying to perform fingerprinting on tor to see how it works

PS: I am really new to scapy so I am unsure if there is a direct method. I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use scapy to collect traffic on a direction *directly*. If you want to do that, use tcpdump or tshark with the `-Q in` or `-Q out`.

What you can likely do is look at the contents of a packet and see which MAC/IP address or TCP/UDP port is sender/receiver for the protocol you're looking at. For example, if you see traffic destined for port 80, and you have a webserver, (and other destination information matches) then that's incoming traffic.

Keep in mind that you can [sniff in scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453283/filter-options-for-sniff-function-in-scapy) with a [BPF filter](https://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html), but that traffic direction is outside of that, and filtering by one of the above will work better.

Comment: Yes, I had an idea like that. I have been capturing the packets only between the client and the guard relay. Would it be reasonable to assume that the there will be more packets sent from the guard relay, i.e the web, and hence all packet with source IP of guard relay are inbound packets?

Comment: If you have more information to add to your question, you should (there's an edit button). You may want to check out how packets travel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125987/how-does-a-packet-travel-from-one-computer-to-another-over-the-internet-based-on